# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService>

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-code, build, apk

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> C:\Sources\iTradeMobileApp\Skien.Suite.Commerce.MobileApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
> activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
> C:\Sources\iTradeMobileApp\Skien.Suite.Commerce.MobileApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-24:19 Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
> C:\Sources\iTradeMobileApp\Skien.Suite.Commerce.MobileApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-35:20 Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar error (which appeared after updating to cordova-android 11) by updating the plugin that was causing it.

In this case there may be an update to the Firebase plugin which has `android:exported` specified.